# cannot run the same code on difterent machines

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a df

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), ctry=c("UK","DE","IT","DE","UK"))
```

When I run this code

```
df <- df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = ctry, values_from = ctry, values_fill = list(ctry = 0))
```

on my Macbook, it works just fine. But when I run the same script file on another Macbook, it keeps showing the error of "Error: Can't convert double to character." What should I do to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a change in the 1.1.0 version of tidyr.  From the change log:

> pivot_wider() arguments values_fn and values_fill can now be single
>   values; you now only need to use a named list if you want to use
>   different values for different value columns (#739, #746). They also
>   get improved errors if they’re not of the expected type

Depending on the version of R and tidyr you may need to convert "ctry" from factor to character and then quote the 0 to also become a character string.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), ctry=c("UK","DE","IT","DE","UK"))
df$ctry <- as.character(df$ctry)
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = ctry, values_from = ctry, 
                    values_fill = list(ctry = "0"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have different versions of R, i am on R 3.6.1 :

```
df %>% pivot_wider(values_from = "ctry", names_from="ctry",values_fill = list(ctry = 0))
Error: Can't cast `x` <double> to `to` <factor<a55ab>>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

In R 4.0 i think the default is stringsAsFactors = FALSE in data.frames. So for this to work:

```
df %>% 
mutate(ctry=as.character(ctry)) %>% 
pivot_wider(values_from = ctry, names_from=ctry,values_fill = list(ctry = 0))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
     id UK    DE    IT   
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 UK    0     0    
2     2 0     DE    0    
3     3 0     0     IT   
4     4 0     DE    0    
5     5 UK    0     0
```